# Line of best fit (Linear regression) over vertical line

Tags: regression, linear-model, fitting

I want to get a line of the best fit which is a line that passes as close as possible to a set of points defined by coordinates point_i = (X_i, Y_i).

When I apply linear regression, I have a special case where the line do not correspond to what I want. It is the case where the data-points are aligned over a vertical line (i.e. Y values do not depend on X values) like the following example for instance (or see the points on image bellow), e.g:

```
Y = [1,2,3,4,5,8,10,11,15,13,21,22,23,24,25,28,30,31,35,33]
X = [1,1,1,1,1,1,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ,1 ];
```

In this case I expect to get a line of best fit which is vertical and passes as close to a set of points, but when I get from regression is a horizontal line ! However, what I'm interested in, is not the error over the Y axis, but I'm interested in the error to minimize which indicate how far (according to distance) are the points from the line of best fit that we get (e.g. the sum of shortest distance from each point to the line).

Is there any why to get such a line and to get the corresponding score which indicates how far are the points this line ?

I think "linear regression" is not the same thing as "line of best fit", and what I want to get is "line of best fit".

[image]

EDIT:

I want to estimate line of best fit for another purpose, not to evaluate how much X and Y are correlated (it is more for a pattern recognition problem, where my data-points are some pixels defined by their coordinates x,y on the image). So I want to fit the line even if X values are not correlated to Y values. And if I just always swap X and Y to be able to fit the line, the next time if I have points lying on a horizontal line (Y = [3,3,3,3], X=[3, 6, 23, 30] for example) the if they are swapped I'll get again the same problem. I want to always fit the line whatever is the correlation between W and Y (even if there is no correlation, like in the example I provided).

So to be more clear: Whatever is the correlation between X and Y, my objective is not to predict some y values based on new values of x, my objective is rather just to get a line which passes as close as possible to all points that we have (even if Y are independent of X ...).

Comment: The answers you are getting seem to be missing the question you are really asking and are hung up on least squares analysis, which is not what you want. Searching our site for [errors-in-variables regression](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=errors-in-variables+regression) and [PCA](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pca?sort=votes) will head you in the right direction. In the meantime, think some more about what you really mean by "close as possible": it's easy to construct (infinitely many) curves that pass *exactly* through your points, in sequence.

Comment: Anyone reading this question may be interested in [this significantly more helpful stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37541478/6506482).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In the case you want to make a linear regression where Y values do not depend on X values, the method is to look for the solution of equation `ny + p = x` instead of the usual `mx + p = y`

---

The principle is the same, using the least square method. It solves the equation `ax = b` by computing a vector `x` that minimizes the Euclidean 2-norm `|| b - a x ||^2`

I've made a script where I compare the two methods (ny + p = x versus mx + p = y) using 3 lines, a diagonal, a horizontal line and a vertical one. I'm displaying the Sum of the residuals (Sum of Res.) in the legend.
You could see that for the diagonal line, the results are similar, but for the vertical and horizontal one, 1 method is giving good results while the other is giving is not.

### Method 1: mx + p = y

The green line equation is not well fitting the values. The sum of residuals is very high compared to the good regression fits like diagonal or horizontal lines.

[image: using method 1]

### Method 2: ny + p = x

The red line equation is not well fitting the values. The sum of residuals is very high compared to the good regression fits like diagonal or vertical lines.

[image: using method 2]

Comment: You are too good!

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this would be to check the point "verticality", regress a line through (X,Y) inverted points, and then invert the regressed line back.

1. **Check point "verticality" by comparing the standard deviations of X and Y values.**

> ```
> stDevX = StandardDeviation(xValues) 
> stDevY = StandardDeviation(yValues) 
>
> verticality = stDevY/stDevX #Handle div/0 cases
> ```

2. **If vertical, regress a line through inverted Y and X points.**

> ```
> isVertical = verticality > 1.5 #adjust based on situation (could be 2.0 or more)
>
> if(isVertical)
>    invertedLine = RegressLine(yValues,xValues) #Note reversed x,y order
> ```

3. **Obtain non-inverted slope and intercept from inverted line**

> ```
> slope = 1/invertedLine.Slope
> intercept = -invertedLine.Intercept / invertedLine.Slope
> ```

Notes:

- This will fail if the points are *perfectly* vertical (ie. stDevX is
  =0). If this is the case, the line equation is just x=Average(xValues). For nearly-vertical lines, the slope will be
  large, but finite.
- The stDevY/stDevX ratio will be approximately equal to the regressed line |slope|. When the points become vertical, the regressed line slope will start to deviate from the ratio. In my case, whenever the ratio exceeded 1.5, the regressed slope became inaccurate, and flipping the axes improved accuracy. You should experiment with your data to find the best verticality threshold.

Answer (score 1):

One purpose of a linear model is to see how a variable varies as a function of variation in another variable - it's basically just a re-parameterized covariance. In your example, you have a variable with zero variation, thus it would be nonsensical to use linear regression. If you still want to fit the line, you could just swap X and Y. The resultant regression coefficient would of course still be zero (indicating no relationship, or slope), and further confirm that knowledge of X (using your original notation) tells us nothing about Y. Given this is true, the question you should answer is, "Why do I want to estimate a line of best fit?"

Comment: I want to estimate line of best fit for another purpose, not to evaluate how much X and Y are correlated (it is more for a pattern recognition problem, where my data-points are some pixels defined by their coordinates x,y on the image). So I want to fit the line even if X values are not correlated to Y values. And if I just always swap X and Y to be able to fit the line, the next time if I have points lying on a horizontal line (Y = [3,3,3,3], X=[3, 6, 23, 30] for example) the if they are swaped I'll get again the same problem. I want to always fit the line whatever is the correlation of X,Y

Comment: So to be more clear: My objective is not to predict some y values based on new values of x, my objective is rather just to get a line which passes as close as possible to all points that we have (even if Y are independent of X ...).

Comment: You can't have a vertical line...because it's not a function. You can have a horizontal line - it will always have an intercept at the mean value of Y, and a slope of zero. Part of my point is that you don't need a model to figure this out.

Comment: Basically, I want to draw a line which is as close as possible to all points (as a linear regression will do in case where Y depends on X) even if there is no correlation between Y and X values ... I want a method which I can apply whatever is the correlation of Y and X (even there is or there no correlation between them) ! How to do that ?

Comment: Your question has been answered - if X varies and Y doesn't, then the equation for your line has intercept = Y and slope = 0. If Y varies and X doesn't, there is no way to estimate that line, but you already know that it's a straight vertical line at the mean of X (which is just X).

Comment: If Y varies and X varies by very slightly, I'll also get the same problem to estimate that line or not ?

Answer (score 1):

The reason why this does not work is because your system (or data, rather) does not fit the linear model.

Your data vector had the problem that each element is exactly the same. In other words if you'd have multiple data vectors you'd have a linear dependend system.
Or put differently yet again - the issue here is perfect multicollinearity.

This is a situation where the linear model is actually not able to give you any information. It might be that you didn't see this point when studying this because it usually comes in a form of "Matrix X is of rank N" or something like that, but it still important.

Think about it:
If your regressand is always 1 as indicated in your data set, it is obviously impossible to put any line through it as the variation of y can not be related to a constant factor. The best approximation, linear wise, is the mean of $y$ which is what you seem to get. This is still the closest you can functionally get to $y$.

But once again just so that you can understand this: If your best functional approximation is a horizontal line, a mean, then the actual data points have to be created by an error term. Intuitively this makes sense: If your x is always the same, how would you ever attribute influence of it on a changing term?

In the end you are looking - in your graph at least - for a measure based on only $x$. In your graph this would be the arithmetic mean of $x$. You can see that even in your graph the $y$ have no bearing on the positioning of your $y$.

A possible solution to your question is actually to flip $x$ and $y$.
What you are looking for then are the residuals of that regression as a measure of "closeness" to the line. This is assuming your $x$ is not actually equal to 1 everywhere.
Use this:  $$x=\alpha+y+\epsilon$$ 
If you are fixed on getting a vertical straight line (not a function) use the model without regressand instead of which will give you the mean of $x$ instead as " horizontal line": $$x=\alpha+\epsilon$$
If you flip that graph, you have your vertical line - or your fitted "almost horizontal line" if you used the first model.
Next, calculate your residuals. These happen to be the differences between your $y$ values and your predicted $y$ values - the fitted or vertical line depending on the model.

This is essentially what you want I guess, though honestly I don't know why.
You can now calculate the sum or residuals, their squares and for that the standard errors and such...

Edit: I am going to assume your edit was targeted at my post?
If you happen to have this problem in both sides you'll have to catch those special cases anyway. Regression technically can not be done on this fringe case as I posted above. You can see this even because you had to modify your graph to display variation in $x$ even though your data says the $x$ is always 1.
In practice, why would you get cases where entries are literally the same? The linear model stays accurate even for cases with a lot of multicollinearity (you don't have to flip n that case).

My final tip would be to add random jitter to your $x$ or $y$ so you don't get that exact problem. But if you are really looking at cases where you can not catch and remove cases of perfect multicollinerity, you are probably asking the wrong question or model tbh

Comment: I think that I was not very clear in my question. I want to fit the data whatever is the correlation between X and Y (this is not regression), the objective is not to predict some y values based on new values of x, my objective is rather to get a line which passes as close as possible to all points that we have.

Comment: This is literally the same thing. Correlation is the linear measure of that relationship and regression is the best linear fit based on covariation. Conceptually you can not relate linear dependend things on an $y$ in a linear system. Throw out those cases or add jitter as I suggested.

Comment: As I said, even when you tried to draw a graph of your problem you intuitively added jitter to your points because otherwise your line would literally be "$y=1$"

Comment: If I give you some data points where X do not change while Y values change. Y do not depends on X. I'm not looking to learn a predictive model. However, I can draw a vertical line which passes over all that points. This is just what I want !

Comment: Ok your line is this then $x = Const$ with $Const$ beeing the value of your $X$. But what do you want with this?

Comment: This is just a special case, we can have data where X do not change and Y values changes, or not. I want to draw a line of best fit in all cases ... whatever is my data.

Comment: And this is not for prediction, it is for a pattern recognition problem, where my points are some pixels defined by their coordinates x,y on the image ...

Comment: I understand that it is not for prediction but you have to realize that this, mathematically, is the same thing. If you are looking specifically for a line which minimizes a measure of distance to points in a (x,y) plane, you are doing a regression. If OLS is the correct way depends on your data but conceptionally you have to realize that you can not have a line in a one-dimensional space - correct? If your problem is simply an algorithm which fails because of perfect multicollinearity, why not catch those cases and add a bit of jitter?

Comment: You don't need to flip either, really. This was just the case where you get this problem in one direction and not the other. And if you want to have a straight line (exactly horizontally or vertically), you will have to always take the mean of those $x$ and $y$ values. Of course you can calculate the residuals of that, but it just isn't really a line. A fitted line, however, IS regression. And seeing that you want a linear solution to this problem, I think doing OLS is not generally wrong. To calculate the residuals or "distance from your line" you need .. the line. This is a prediction.

Comment: I can not catch this special case where Y do not depends on X, can I ? How ? Or should I always add some noise to my X values ?!

Comment: Are you using R? Matlab? What format is your data? You can check if those values are always the same, right? Otherwise you can calculate the covariance matrix of the $X$ and $Y$ vector and look how close the correlation is to 1. You might want to add jitter if it is too close. Or instead, you can then just say "okay now it is a straight line in THAT direction" and take the mean of either $x$ and $y$. This arises just from the fact that you try to fit a coninous line through discrete (pixel) datapoints. This is not the mistake of regression and you'll have to code around it anyway so

Comment: And your regression will still give you the best fit if those values are "almost identical". Especially if you only have two dimensions. It's just this very fringe case where you have no variation in either variable which let's the algorithm fail. The case in your graph, for example, should be solved by any regression algorithm. It's just that the line will not be perfectly straight. If you want it to be straight, you can for example take the endpoints of your regressed line and calculate the arithmetic mean as a line constant. Possibilities are endless but you will HAVE to code

Comment: Ok, I'll test using the coefficient of correlation and add some random noise to x (is this want you call jitter?) is the correlation is close to 1. I'm using python, sklearn, and the format of the data is just a matrix.

Comment: Yes that is a possibility. A better way is to check the correlation and if it is close to 1 just use the mean for the line either horizontally or vertically. The random noise (jitter) variation of this idea had a different context: If those cases are very rare but exact precision is not important, adding the random noise allows your algorithm to not fail. So if you have a lot of data points, you could add random noise to all data points and then you can save the time it takes to check correlation. If precision is important then you need to check and maybe use a straight line or add noise.

Comment: Or (1) is it possible to just flip/swap X and Y when the coefficient of correlation is close to 1 ?! (2) It will be close to 1 if we have the case that I shown on the image that I posted ?

Comment: (1) If the values are the same the variance of the $x$ or $y$ would be zero. The correlation bit was where I got confused with the multivariate case, sorry. Check if either variance is close to zero.

Comment: The correlation would not be one. The correlation would also be zero. Sorry for that.

Comment: the correlation for those values with each other would be 1. Anyway, swapping alone will not help so either use the value which has no variation as line or add noise, depending on what is quicker and better in your data.